# Easy way to test python class in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I was just wondering the easiest way to test a python class using VScode/terminal. Example, I have this code.

```
class GaussDiscrimAnalysis:
def __init__(self, inputList):
    self.mainList = inputList
    self.numOfFeatures = inputList.length - 1
    self.thetas = [0.0] * self.numOfFeatures
    self.numOfExamples = inputList.length
    self.yLoc = self.numOfFeatures

def calcPhi(self):
    initalSum = 0.0
    for i in self.mainList:
        initalSum+=i[self.yLoc]
    initalSum/=self.numOfExamples
    self.phi = initalSum
```

I want to be able to create a small input and create a GaussDiscrimAnalysis object using said unput and then run the specific functions (such as calcPhi) either from the terminal or some VScode extension.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class GaussDiscrimAnalysis:
    def __init__(self, inputList):
        self.mainList = inputList
        self.numOfFeatures = len(input_list) - 1    # (1)
        self.thetas = [0.0] * self.numOfFeatures
        self.numOfExamples = len(input_list)    # (1)
        self.yLoc = self.numOfFeatures

    def calcPhi(self):
        initalSum = 0.0

        for i in self.mainList:
            initalSum += i[self.yLoc]    # (2)

        initalSum /= self.numOfExamples

        self.phi = initalSum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('input.txt') as f:
        input_list = list(map(int, f.readline().strip().split()))
    
    gauss_discr_analysis = GaussDiscrimAnalysis(input_list)
    gauss_discr_analysis.calcPhi()

    print (gauss_discr_analysis.phi)
```

Some notes on the code that I pasted:

1. For the two lines of code marked with (1) I replaced the `.length` call with `len()`
2. The line marked with (2) is surely doing something wrong. When iterating through the list elements, `i` is a number and your code was trying to access the `self.yLoc` th element of number. Please replace `i` with the proper list object
3. I saved the script in a file called `gauss.py` on my Desktop
4. The input for the script is a list of numbers saved in a file called `input.txt` saved also on my Desktop

e.g.

[image]

5. I opened the terminal in VS Code, changed the current directory to the Desktop and executed `python gauss.py` (this assumes that you have python added to system path) and the code runs properly once you fix that bug marked with (2)